# Which algorithm would be most suitable for finding a minimum subgraph that connects all vertices in a graph and has the smallest weight?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, artificial-intelligence

Which algorithm would be most suitable Kruskal, Prims or Steiner tree algorithm  ?

Comment: Are you talking about minimum spanning forest?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about edge weights, that is the minimum spanning tree problem. You can use either Prim or Kruskal. Practically, Prim is probably easier to implement and faster.